# What's wrong in this "counterexample" of the Moyal´s product associativity?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, exterior-algebra

I have been working in the phase space formulation of quantum mechanics, and stumbled upon the following problem:
Consider the phase space functions :

> $e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar}$, $e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}$ and $W(x,p)$,

where $e^{\pm ip\epsilon /\hbar}$ are asociated with forward and backwards quantum tranlsation operators, $W(x,p)$ is a Wigner pseudoprobability function, and as usual $x$ stands for position and $p$ for momentum.
I need to compute the quantity

> $e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar} * W(x,p)* e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}$

Where * represents the Moyal product,

> $A(x,p)*B(x,p)= A(x,p) e^{i \Lambda \hbar/2} B(x,p)$
>
> $\Lambda= \overleftarrow{\partial_p}$  $\vec{\partial_x} $ -    $\overleftarrow{\partial_x}$  $\vec{\partial_p} $

On one hand, using Moyal´s product associativity and computing

> $e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar} * W(x,p)* e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}=e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar} * [W(x,p)* e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}]$
>
> $=e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar}*[e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}e^{-\epsilon\partial_x/2}W(x,p)]$
>
> $=e^{-\epsilon\partial_x}W(x,p)$

Which I verified using other methods its the correct result. On the other hand, using the following property of Moyal´s product

> $A(x,p) e^{\Lambda \hbar/2} B(x,p)= B(x,p) e^{-\Lambda \hbar/2} A(x,p)$

I can rearrange:

> $e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar} * W(x,p)* e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}=e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar} e^{\Lambda \hbar/2} e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}e^{-\Lambda \hbar/2} W(x,p)$

Now invoking asociativity,

> $=[e^{ip\epsilon /\hbar} * e^{-ip\epsilon /\hbar}]e^{-\Lambda \hbar/2} W(x,p)$
> $=[1] e^{-\Lambda \hbar/2} W(x,p)$
> $=W(x,p)$

Clearly there must be a failure in the above reasoning, or I have misused the product´s properties somewhere, but I cannot find the mistake.
Can anyone point me out where I screwed up?

Answer (score 1):

You assumed, in your last equation, an "associativity" which does not exist! That is,
$$
C * (A * B) = C * (B \bar{*} A)\neq (C * B ) \bar {*}A.
$$
I have defined the complex conjugate $\bar{*}= *^{-1}$, naturally. For simplicity, w.l.o.g., take $\hbar=2$

It is easiest to confirm it fails from, e.g. the integral representation of the * product, eqn (14) of  [A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space, 2014](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf), ISBN: 978-981-4520-43-0, where associativity for *plain unmixed*  *-chains is  straightforward to prove.

In fact, your last equation is a nifty counterexample illustrating this for mixed chains.

Here is a straightforward elementary counterexample. Take $A=x, ~ B=p, ~ C=e^p$. Then,
$$
A*B=xp-i=B\bar{*}A,\\
C*(A*B)=C*(B\bar{*}A)= e^p(-i+xp+ip);\\
C*B= pe^p,\\
(C*B)\bar{*}A= e^p(px-i-ip)~.
$$